# Referring to "this" as a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm learning about c++11 features, specifically `shared_ptr`, and I am having an issue with referring to `this` and using it as a reference for other classes.

The reason for doing this is I have a `Simulation` instance that is passed around to other instances within the simulation (e.g. `Apple`) so they can themselves modify the simulation, or even remove themselves from the simulation.

In my more complex code I get a `double free` error (when the program exists) which as I understand [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848690/11125) that I should not create a `shared_ptr` twice on the same raw object. How do I pass `this` to the `Apple` object as a `shared_ptr` when the Simulation class doesn't know that `this` is already a `shared_ptr`?

My thought is to pass the `shared_ptr` in the initialisation argument but that seems redundant, e.g.:

```
// The argument is a std::shared_ptr<Simulation>
simulation->initSomethingElse(simulation);
```

Maybe I am trying to implement this in an unusual pattern, or maybe my understanding is not quite right? Maybe there is a nicer way of doing this instead?

I have a simplified example below:

```
#include <memory>

class Simulation;

class Apple {
public:
    void init(std::shared_ptr<Simulation> simulation) {
        this->simulation = simulation;
    };

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Simulation> simulation;

};


class Simulation {
public:
    void initSomethingElse() {
        auto apple = std::shared_ptr<Apple>(new Apple());

        // incorrect second reference to the raw pointer
        apple->init(std::shared_ptr<Simulation>(this));
    };
};


int main() {

    auto simulation = std::shared_ptr<Simulation>(new Simulation());
    simulation->initSomethingElse();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you destroying the `shared_ptr<Simulation>` instances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use `enable_shared_from_this`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

But the second thing that comes to mind is that the Simulation should be managing the lifetime of the Apple, so the Apple need not manage the lifetime of the Simulation.  Therefore, you are better off having the Apple not hold a `shared_ptr<Simulation>` - only `main()` or some high-level function should manage the lifetime of the Simulation.

If you aren't careful you will end up with cyclic references.  Don't assume every pointer in C++11 should be a shared_ptr.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence alone

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) so a function on the object can create a new `shared_ptr` to itself.  You'll want to do this instead of the `apple->init(std::shared_ptr<Simulation>(this));` line that creates a second `shared_ptr` to the `Simulation`.  You'll also want to rturn or save the `apple` `shared_ptr` somewhere, as at present the `Apple` only exists while `initSomethingElse()` is running, which doesn't seem very useful...?